# How is the output voltage of a mobile phone charger fixed to a rated value?

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, charger, power-electronics, mobile

[image]
Here is the circuit of cellphone charger. I have seen the input voltage range for a cellphone charger to be 100-230 V but the output voltage to be fixed to the rated value(like ~4.5 V). So, my question is how the output voltage is fixed to the optimized value if I provide different mains supply voltage. Like, in India I give 220 V RMS value while in Japan I provide 100 V RMS.The grid frequency is also different in different countries as well as the RMS voltge.
I am attaching a picture of the rating of an ac adapter(cellphone charger).-

[image]

Comment: The block labelled "Regulator" does that.

Comment: your question is answered in that one..

Comment: The regulator block keeps it at the necessary voltage. If you apply more or less power on the AC line, then the regulator is responsible to dissipate more or less heat (respectively) in order to maintain a constant voltage.

Comment: Typically regulators have heat sinks to dissipate the heat such that the circuit does not get too hot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "wide range" chargers do not just have a transformer and a rectifier inside but some electronic curcuitry.
They use so called switching regulators.
So basically there is first a rectifier that rectifies the mains voltage so we have a 150V or 300V DC Voltage. Now we basically use a transistor to switch this voltage on and off trough a really small transformer (but at a high frequency).
The switching regulator measures the output voltage and controls the power transistor that switches the high voltage.

This way you can build a system that accepts a wide range of input voltages and still delivers a stable output. It's small, quite efficient and cheap.